# Change font color for text input in dropdown for dash plotly

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm trying to change the color of the text when I type in the dcc.dropdown in my dash application.
The color of the elements of the dropdown is fine but the text input looks like is on the default one.

Any help?

Thank you.

[dropdown input text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH2Cf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.  Just need to specify the color option in the style argument.  Can choose whatever color you like - here's a list of CSS colors you can choose: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp

```
dcc.Dropdown(id='dd',
               style={'color': 'black'},
               options=[{'label':i,'value':i} for i in choices],
               value=choices[0]
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while ago but I came across the same issue and couldn't find an answer anywhere. You can resolve this issue in the CSS:

```
.Select input{
  color:white;
}
```